# Why this chain of promises immediately resolves?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Can someone explain to me why the resulting promise (`d`) from the code below is resolved immediately?

```
//promises that are never resolved nor rejected
var a = new Promise(function(r,re){});
var b = new Promise(function(r,re){});
var c = new Promise(function(r,re){});

var d = [a, b, c].reduce(function (previousPromise, promise) {
    return previousPromise.then(promise);
  }, Promise.resolve());
```

I'm creating an array of promises that are pending forever, so the resulting promise should also be pending forever as it waits for all subsequent promises to finish ([as presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372320/how-to-chain-execution-of-array-of-functions-when-every-function-returns-deferre)). I've been using promises for a while now, but I'm clearly missing something here.

[image: Chrome DevTools - promises code executed]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`then` doesn't take a `Promise` as an input, it takes 2 functions, 1 for fulfillment and 1 for rejection.

The reason `d` is resolved is due to the fact that calling .then with a non-callable value (even a number literal - 1, or `undefined`) causes the onFulfilled function to be replace by "Identity", which simply re-fulfills with whatever value was resolved in the previous step. See [PerformPromiseThen](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)

Try like this:

```
//promises that are never resolved nor rejected
var a = function() { return new Promise(function(r,re){}); };
var b = function() { return new Promise(function(r,re){}); };
var c = function() { return new Promise(function(r,re){}); };
// or simply, a = b = c after setting the function for c

var d = [a, b, c].reduce(function (previousPromise, fn) {
    return previousPromise.then(fn, /* not passing a rejection handler... */);
  }, Promise.resolve());
```

Or alternatively...

```
//promises that are never resolved nor rejected
var a = new Promise(function(r,re){});
var b = new Promise(function(r,re){});
var c = new Promise(function(r,re){});

var d = [a, b, c].reduce(function (previousPromise, promise) {
    return previousPromise.then(function() {return promise;});
  }, Promise.resolve());
```

And since you're using promises & ES6, you could be more concise:

```
let a = new Promise(() => {});
let b = new Promise(() => {});
let c = new Promise(() => {});

let d = [a, b, c].reduce((previousPromise, promise) =>
  previousPromise.then(() => promise),
  Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: How come `Promise.resolve().then(new Promise(function(r, re) {}))` resolves to a pending promise?

Comment: @RGraham it doesn't really

Comment: It is 'pending' for a split second while the `new Promise(...)` waits to be executed. As Promise handlers are executed asynchronously Chrome will log the Promise immediately, but if you assign the Promise to a variable and _then_ log it, you will see it is resolved.

Comment: @sdgluck No, I tried that too. http://i.imgur.com/v7ATbeq.png. .@Amit That's what I assumed. Although I see why this answers the question, I'm not sure how the OP is getting a resolved promise from their code because I'm not.

Comment: no, you're right ... but I don't fully understand it to be honest, but the `Promise.resolve();` logs fulfilled, whereas `Promise.resolve().then()` is pending because the `then` is executed in the next event loop or something ... it does my head in trying to think about it to be honest

Comment: @sdgluck Ha! I'll have to do some investigating on my side. Still can't replicate that here.

Comment: calling `.then` with a non-callable value (even a number literal - `1`) causes the onFulfilled function to be replace by "Identity", which simply re-fulfills with whatever value was resolved in the previous step. See [PerformPromiseThen](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)

Comment: @RGraham in the console, compare this - `d = Promise.resolve('stuff').then(); d` with `d = Promise.resolve('stuff').then();` (on a new line just type `d`) ...

Comment: @Amit - this question makes sense now!

Comment: @JaromandaX - You're right, I should (and will!) add this last part to the answer itself...

Answer (score -1):

```
var d = [a, b, c].reduce(function (previousPromise, promise) {
    return previousPromise.then(promise);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Your initial state of d promise is resolved, you set is as Promise.resolve(). Check documentation of reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: This is incorrect. A Promise's fulfilment or rejection does not waterfall and affect a subsequent Promise's status.