# How to run an array of promises in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I need to run some promises on an array of items but I don't know the length of the array. How do I run these promises in sequence? This is how I do it asynchronously:

```
const arrayABC = [a, b, c.....x, y, z] // length unknown
const promises = arrayABC.map(function(item) {
   doSomething(item)
   }
return Promise.all(promises)
```

I need the promises to run through them one by one.

Comment: A duplicate (?) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21372335/251311

Comment: This question has been exhaustively answered here on SO. Please do a bit more searching.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your setup correctly, this seems the most reasonable approach:

```
// return the promise chain from last element
return arrayABC.reduce(function (chain, item) {
  // bind item to first argument of function handle, replace `null` context as necessary
  return chain.then(doSomething.bind(null, item));
// start chain with promise of first item
}, doSomething(arrayABC.shift()));
```

Comment: Reducing the array that is mutated in the same expression looks ugly. One might just pass a dummy resolved promise as an initial value instead.

Comment: @zerkms that would waste event loops

Comment: One event loop iteration vs controversial code... :-S

Comment: How is it controversial? It's well-defined that the mutation occurs first. There's no such thing as undefined behavior in JavaScript.

Comment: I did not say it's undefined behaviour. I said, using mutation (which is not free - at least in current v8 implementation it allocates a new array and fills it with old data. So your shift is O(N) in terms of both operations and memory) to save one event loop iteration is an arguable choice. It is usually not the best idea to mutate a collection you're iterating over. I'm not insisting though, it's up to everybody how to write their code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're down with using bluebird - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html - you can use `.each()` to run them sequentially. Example taken from the documentation comments

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

let queue = [];

queue.push(function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Some asynchronous task.
    console.log("Processing item 1...");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
});

queue.push(function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Some asynchronous task.
    console.log("Processing item 2...");
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
});

Promise.each(queue, function(queue_item) {
  // *Now* we call the function. Since it returns a promise, the next iteration will not run until it resolves.
  return queue_item();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The following mapping is *asynchronous* and *sequential*, while your code is *asynchronous* and *parallel*.

```js
function sequentialAsyncMap(array, fn) {
    var p = Promise.resolve();
    return Promise.all(array.map(
        (item, index, collection) => p = p.then(
            () => fn(item, index, collection)
        )
    ));
}

function delay(timeout, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), timeout);
    });
}

sequentialAsyncMap([1, 2, 3], i => {
    console.log(i);
    return delay(500, 2*i);
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to access all the Promises results (like you can with Promise.all) - you can do the following:

```
Promise.series = (array, fn, thisArg) => {
    var p = Promise.resolve();
    return Promise.all(Array.from(array).map((...args) => 
        p = p
        .then(() => fn.apply(thisArg, args))
    ));
};
```

Then your code becomes

```
const arrayABC = [a, b, c.....x, y, z] // length unknown
return Promise.series(promises, doSomething);
```

The callback (in this case `doSomething`) will be passed the arguments `item, index, array`, just like `Array#map`, `Array#forEach` etc

`thisArg` is optional, and works just like how you would use it for `Array#map`, `Array#forEach` etc

An alternative `Promise.series`

```
Promise.series = (array, fn, thisArg) => 
    Array.from(array).reduce((promise, ...args) => 
        promise
        .then(results => 
            fn.apply(thisArg, args)
            .then(result => results.concat(result))
        ), Promise.resolve([])
    );
```

same result, but no need for `Promise.all`