# is there any method in bluebird which works like async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am doing something like this in which first function is dependent dependent on second .

```
let findOrg = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.organization.find({
                where: data
            })
            .then(org => {
                return resolve(org);
            }).catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    }); };

let createOrg = org => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (org) {
            return resolve(org);
        }
        db.organization.build(data)
            .save()
            .then((org) => {
                return resolve(org);
            }).catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    }); };

findOrg()
    .then(org => { //going to find org
        return createOrg(org); //then going to make org
    }).then(newOrg => {
        res.data(mapper.toModel(newOrg)); //then mapping
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.failure(err);
    });
```

in both above function findOrg and createOrg new promise (**ES6**) are created

My ques is --
 1. how we can solve this in `Bluebird` promise library (in sequence if one function is dependent on other) like

```
async.waterfall([
function(){},
function(){}],
function(){})
```

2. here 2 promises are created .is there any way i

Comment: What is *data*? It is nowhere given a value...

Comment: I think you can do what async.waterfall does by using the promise as intended with no extra complexity. `a().then(b).then(c).catch(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bluebird's [`Promise.reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) or create your own *waterfall* (*chain*) function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35546630/5459839) as alternative.

**But**: your code has unnecessary overhead in using the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it): you can write it without using `new Promise`, and with `.bind` you also avoid creating inline functions explicitly, ... like this:

```
let findOrg = () => db.organization.find({where: data});

let createOrg = org => org || db.organization.build(data).save();

findOrg()
    .then(createOrg)
    .then(mapper.toModel.bind(mapper))
    .then(res.data.bind(res))
    .catch(res.failure.bind(res));
```

This is quite clean in my opinion.

Comment: you don't think so promise.reduce will work like `async.each` ?? in which it takes one element and make execution for it .. then pick other and  make same execution for other also .. i want unique executions for different fuctions

Comment: `promise.reduce` can take an array of promises, and execute them one after the other. The documentation says: *If the reducer function returns a promise, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration.* To my understanding of your question, that is exactly what you want.