# I am using nodemailer and I need to send email to all the users in a array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodejs with nodemailer for sending emails to users.

I have a list of users like this :-

```json
[
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john@something.com"
  }, 
  { 
    name: "Jane Doe",
    email: "jane@something.com"
  }
  ...and more.
]
```

How can I send email to all the users in array using nodemailer.

See my code -

```js
users.map(user => {
          const mailOptions = {
              from: '*****@gmail.com',
              to: user.email,
              subject: subject, // Any subject
              text: message // Any message
          }

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
              } else {
                  console.log(info)   
              }
          })
   })
```

Is this a correct way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This information is not adequate to understand what exactly do you want...

Comment: Hey! @decpk, I want to send a email to all the users in a array.

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412815/sending-multiple-emails-at-once-with-nodemailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work. But if you want to send the same email to many recipients, there is an easier way to do this.

As you can see in the [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/), the field `to` is a `comma-separated list or an array of recipients email addresses that will appear on the To: field`. So something like this will do the job

```
const userEmails = users.map(item => item.email); // array of user email
const mailOptions = { // send the same email to many users
    from: '*****@gmail.com',
    to: userEmails, 
    subject: subject, // Any subject
    text: message // Any message
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err)
   } else {
      console.log(info)   
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array of emails to a comma separated string

```js
const recipients = users.map(user=>user.email).join(',');
// 'john@something.com','jane@something.com'
```

Now you have all the recipients. Next use the `nodemailer` [example](https://nodemailer.com/about/#example) to send emails to all the recipient at once

Comment: What is the max. number of people I can send email with this method ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it depends on the email server you're using